# In JoJo: Diamond is Unbreakable, why didn't Joseph use Hermit Purple to find Kira's new identity?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

The whole point of bringing Joseph to Morioh was to make him use Hermit Purple.

So why didn't he use it to find Kira after he changed his appearance?

Comment: My bet is it was an oversight in writing =P

Comment: "Araki forgot" is not applicable on this one considering there are so many hints to this. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's because Joseph Joestar is growing senile.
Stands are the manifestation of the user's spirit.
Remember that episode when Polnareff became young because of 
Alessi's Stand? Silver Chariot was weak when he was a kid.

**Durability** or *Permanence* is a category in a stand stat which also affects stands as they age too or when not in practice. (A great example would be Star Platinum's initial 1.5 second Timestop turned 2.0 seconds by the middle of Part 4. After the events of Part 6, Jotaro trained himself again to protect those he needs as he have learned in Part 4. He later regained his 5 second time stop, the maximum seconds the human body can achieve.)

So in a sense, if a stand user grows ***old***, it affects also their stands. Likewise, if a stand is not used that much, it gets weaker. Hermit Purple is the stand manifestation of ***Hamon***. As there are no more threats, vampires, and Aztec demigods, Joseph Joestar didn't use it that much (also Joseph Joestar isn't the kind of person to practice. He relies on his cunning). Should he still practice it, I bet he'd still look young even on his 50s in Part 3 just like ***Lisa Lisa***.

On a hindsight, Hermit Purple's ability to search Stand Users was hazy because there are a lot of Stand Users in Morioh. Just like when he tried to divine Kira but found Angelo instead.

**TL;DR** Joseph Joestar can't use Hermit Purple efficiently because he is old and doesn't practice it that much.

Comment: nice job person

Answer (score 0):

Joseph used Hermit Purple to find Dio because Dio had Jonathan's body. They shared the same blood. Kira was not related to Joseph. That's my guess.

Comment: But he used Hermit Purple to find the water dude in the beginning of the anime, which was what made Jotaro even go to Morioh in the first place.

Comment: I think its due to how old he is now. Even when he was young, he had to break a lot of cameras to get a "usable" photograph to find Dio, making the stand not that reliable. I could be wrong tho

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer to change it to what you said in this comment. Your previous answer may be a little bit correct or a coincidence, but you can keep it in if you want.